# Pandas GroupBy Multiple Columns and apply function on one column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on this type of pandas dataframe:

| Chapter | label_code | annotator | rounded_lenght |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chapter1 | 1 | 1 | 159 |
| Chapter 2 | 3 | 2 | 30 |
| Chapter 2 | 4 | 2 | 150 |

I'm trying to apply Krippendorff's alpha on this data frame to calculate inter-annotator agreement for every chapter of the book and for every emotion separately. Here is the function to calculate inter-annotator agreement on this data frame.

```
def krippendorffs_emotion(chapters):
return sf.calculate_krippendorffs_alpha_for_df(chapters, experiment_col='rounded_length', annotator_col='annotator', class_col='label_code')
```

The columns: 
'label_code' is eight different emotions encoded as a number. 
'annotator' encode different annotators 
'rounded_lenght' identify the parts of my text 
and the 'chapter' column encodes different chapters of the book.

To apply this function I need to group this data frame by chapters and I need separate results for every label_code

This is what I've tried.

```
grouped_df = emo_chapters_df.groupby(['Chapter','label_code']).apply(kripendorf_emotion(emo_chapters_df))
grouped_df
```

When I run this code I receive :

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to dispose a little sample of your data, that way we can work on top of it

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, all you want to do is to have a single return on your multiple groups name.

In this case a simple slice of your dataframe shall limit the results to series possibilitating a single return

```
emo_chapters_df.groupby(['Chapter','label_code'])['Column you want to be returned from multiple groupby'].apply(your_funct)
```

Now if you want to return the df object, and formulate a condition on a single give column, that is another question.